# Dynamically sized array of pointers to linked lists

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize an array of pointers to linked lists that has a dynamic size based on user input.

I've got a struct as follows:

```
struct HashTable {
int tableSize;
int (*getKey)(void *);
char *  (*toString)(void *);
void (*freeHashObject)(void *);
Boolean (*compare)(void *, void *);
ListPtr table;
};
```

The table variable is supposed to contain a dynamic number of linked lists depending on user input. You can assume that n is a valid integer and that createHashObject works as it is supposed to.

```
HashTablePtr table;
HashObjectPtr job;
table = createHashTable(n, getKey, toString, freeHashObject, compare);

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    job = createHashObject(firstInput);
    HashInsert(table, job);
}
```

I believe the problem lies in createHashTable which is as follows.

```
HashTablePtr createHashTable(int size, int (*getKey)(void *), 
char * (*toString)(void *), void (*freeHashObject)(void *), 
Boolean (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
HashTablePtr h = (HashTablePtr)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
//dont worry that i dont do things with the function pointers
h -> table = (ListPtr)malloc(sizeof(List)*size);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    h -> table[i] = createList(getKey, toString, freeHashObject);
}
}
```

The above code doesn't seem to correctly initialize all the linked lists. Here is the code for the createList function and the List struct.

```
ListPtr createList(int(*getKey)(void *), 
               char * (*toString)(void *),
               void (*freeHashObject)(void *))
{
ListPtr list;
list = (ListPtr) malloc(sizeof(List));
list->size = 0;
list->head = NULL;
list->tail = NULL;
list->getKey = getKey;
list->toString = toString;
list->freeObject = freeHashObject;
return list;
}

struct list {
int size;
NodePtr head;
NodePtr tail;
int (*getKey)(void *);
char *  (*toString)(void *);
void (*freeObject)(void *);
};
```

I am willing to wager that the issue lies in how I am defining the dynamically sized array of pointers to the linked lists and then initializing it. Can anyone offer me some help with that?

Thank you.

Comment: `createHashTable` should `return h;`, bottom struct should be capitalised...is it homework? What is the evidence of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `HashTable` structure change the `table` definition to declare it as pointer, as below

```
struct HashTable {
    ...
    ListPtr *table;
};
```

Then you can allocate as many you want which you have done correctly.

Comment: @sje397 and Rohan thank you both! Your combined answers helped me, I can't believe that's all it was.